# How to extend BreezeJS to support Badgerfish notation for JSON request data?

Tags: breeze, badgerfish

I'm looking for a starting point on how to extend BreezeJS (or if it's even possible!) to support sending JSON data using the [Badgerfish notation](http://www.sklar.com/badgerfish/) to the server from BreezeJS.

I see that BreezeJS has the `JsonResultsAdapter` - to take a response from the server and transform it - which would work to allow Breeze to walk through a Badgerfish JSON result set and instantiate entities.

I need the other way - a `JsonRequestAdapter` (or something like it) - to take the JSON that Breeze has created and about to send to the server, and modify to the Badgerfish notation.

Any guidance for this problem? thanks!

**Update: June 2013**

I've gone with the approach of implementing a custom Breeze DataService adapter that I pass into an EntityManager instance.  This approach is not for the faint of heart to be honest, and took some work to really understand what needed to happen.  I took the provided Web API DataService adapter and 'adapted' it to work for a generic RESTful service.

Answer (score 0):

Adam, this is a **great** question.

We are trying to come up with a standard mechanism analagous to the 'JsonResultsAdapter' to be used to intecept http 'puts' but really want to understand the most common use cases first.  We'd love any feedback on suggestions and use cases.

Please add a 'feature request' for this to the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions).  We take these suggestions very seriously and this is a topic that we think is important as well, but really want to get some feedback from our community on its priority.